# Classify: other output representation

Tags: output, machine-learning

I'm working on a classisfy problem. The code is like:

```
CMDDrf = Classify[trainingdata, Method -> "RandomForest"]
```

Then I want to make a prediction based on a other file (testSample):

```
fc = Table[{testSample[[i, 1]], 
    CMDDrf[testSample[[i, 2 ;; 10]], "Probabilities"]}, {i, 
    Length[testSample]}] // TableForm
```

The output is:

> {{121, <|AAA-> 0.2, BBB-> 0.34, CCC-> 0.46|>},  {122, <|AAA-> 0.3,
>   BBB-> 0.24, CCC-> 0.36|>},  {123, <|AAA-> 0.6, BBB-> 0.14, CCC->
>   0.26|>}}
>
> The output I would like to get is:
>
> {{121, 0.2, 0.34, 0.46},  {122, 0.3, 0.24, 0.36},  {123, 0.6, 0.14,
>   0.26}}

Is there a option in the classify-function to het this representation. Or who knows a work around to get the desired output?

Comment: I'd get rid of `Table` (functional programming FTW), and do something like `{x,AAA,BBB,CCC}/.Join[{Rule[x,#[[1]]]},CMDDrf[#[[2;;10]]]&/@testSample`

Comment: Missed a couple of brackets and a necessary `Normal` function. `{x,AAA,BBB,CCC} /. 
   Join[{Rule[x, #[[1]]]}, 
    Normal[CDMDrf[#[[2;;10]], "Probabilities"]]] & /@ testSample`